# MySQL Tag System (3 tables) - How to select the last 10 published posts and all the tags associated to each post?

Tags: mysql

I'm implementing a Tag System for my website, using PHP + MySQL.

In my database, I have three tables:

**posts**

| id | title | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |

Primary Key: id

**tags**

| id | tag | slug |
| --- | --- | --- |

Primary Key: id | Key: slug

**tagsmap**

| id | tag |
| --- | --- |

Primary Key: both

(id = post's id in posts; tag = tag's id in tags)

Every post may have one or more tags, or no tags, associated to it.

Now I need to select - and show on the same page - the last 10 (no less, no more) published posts and all the tags associated to those posts.

This is what I've tried:

```
SELECT 
  p.title, 
  t.slug, 
  t.tag 
FROM 
  posts p 
  LEFT JOIN tagsmap tm ON p.id = tm.id 
  LEFT JOIN tags t ON tm.tag = t.id 
WHERE 
  p.datetime <= NOW() 
ORDER BY 
  p.id DESC 
LIMIT 
  10
```

It works, but, doing so, posts having two tags are showed twice, while I need to show each post just once.

Then I've added

```
GROUP BY p.id
```

But, this way, I get only one tag for each post.

I don't know how to solve this problem (I'm not very experienced with MySQL).

Would you give me any suggestions?

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/281578/1/0)

**P.S.: What I need is a SQL-side (not PHP-side) solution (the best in terms of performance). Nevertheless, any further suggestions would be much appreciated.**

Comment: *"It works, but, doing so, posts having two tags are showed twice, while I need to show each post just once."* do it on application side (php), not SQL-side

Comment: _"posts having two tags are showed twice, while I need to show each post just once"_ - but then how would you get the _two_ tags ...? GROUP_CONCAT exists, but that is a rather "unclean" way of doing such things. It should really rather be your output logic here, that transforms those two records into however you want to display your tags.

Comment: Please provide the expected output.

Comment: *I need to select the last 10 published posts* Get last 10 posts in subquery or CTE then join tags. *posts having two tags are showed twice, while I need to show each post just once.* GROUP BY + GROUP_CONCAT().

Comment: @Nishant Gupta The expected output is clearly described in my question: I need to select (and show on my website) the last 10 published posts and all the tags associated to each post (see Post #1 and Post #2 in SQL Fiddle).

Comment: Do You want tags in separate column or in one column in case a post has more than 1 tag?

Comment: @Nishant Gupta Now I would try both solutions, because I don't know which is better. Your advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Akina Wouldn't it be better (in terms of performance) executing two separate SQL queries? I mean, one for posts and one for tags.

Comment: Excess network transfers... I doubt.

Comment: CTE is overkill.  And possibly slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First select the latest 10 posts and then join to the other tables.
Then group by post and use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to combine all slugs and tags in a comma separated string for each post:

```
SELECT p.title, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(t.slug ORDER BY t.id) slugs, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag ORDER BY t.id) tags 
FROM (SELECT * FROM posts WHERE datetime <= NOW() ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 10) p 
LEFT JOIN tagsmap tm ON p.id = tm.id 
LEFT JOIN tags t ON tm.tag = t.id 
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.datetime DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8cede9e7041ef672c45cbaa126df63da).

Comment: Why `GROUP BY p.id, p.title` instead of simply `GROUP BY p.id`?

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner because id is not defined as the primary key of the table (at least this is what I see in the fiddle). Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6fef12f8efc68bba8729d04252fc5a57

Comment: In my DB, id is defined as the primary key of the "posts" table (see question); that's why in my app `GROUP BY p.id` works fine. I'll edit my fiddle.

Comment: Then GROUP BY p.id only is fine. I will edit.

Comment: Sadly, there's a problem with this query: I've just added a new post scheduled for tomorrow, and now posts currently selected are 9 instead of 10. Same result with your demo.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner for this case the WHERE clause should be in the subquery and not the main query. I edited.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you prefer `ORDER BY (p.)datetime` instead of `ORDER BY (p.)id`?

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner I assume that you want the results sorted by datetime descending. If you are sure that the ids are always in the same order as the datetime then there is no difference.

Comment: @forpas - Well, usually no difference.  If two rows have identical `datetime` values, then...  To fix that:  `ORDER BY datetime DESC, id DESC`.  _And_ this might run faster if `datetime` is indexed.

Comment: @RickJames I don't see identical datetimes in the sample data. If there are then the id can be used to break the tie.

Comment: @forpas - True, no dups in the sample.  But, as you say, there could be a tie in the 'real world'.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, `GROUP_CONCAT` is the 'answer'.  But to make the schema better and faster, I suggest:

- Get rid of `slug` (if possible).  If "posts" need slugs, then put them into `Posts`.  If a "slug" is a type of "tag", then treat it as such.  For that matter, consider throwing category, date, author, etc, into `Tags`.
- Combine `tagmap` and `tag`.  The loss in normalization is more than made up for by avoiding the double-JOIN.
- (for clarity) `id` should only refer to the current table; `post_id` should be used to refer to the posts table.

  ```
    CREATE TABLE Tags (
        post_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        tag VARCHAR(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(post_id, tag),
        INDEX(tag)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

    SELECT p.title, 
           ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tag SEPARATOR ', ') tags WHERE post_id = p.id ) AS tags
        FROM posts AS p
        ORDER BY p.datetime DESC
        LIMIT 10;
  ```

When the tables get big, this formulation has the advantage of avoiding the "explode-implode" that is caused by `JOIN + GROUP BY`.

That subquery will return `NULL` when there are no tags; use `COALESCE()` if you want to turn `NULL` int `''` or `(no tags)` or whatever.

When you get into "pagination", don't use `OFFSET`.  Instead, "remember where you left off", See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination

If you need the latest 10 posts *with a certain tag*, then see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/lists

Comment: Do you mean `FROM posts p`? Also, there's no datetime condition in your query.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner - Yes.  Fixed.